# RedirectToAction to the same action but without the route values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'll show what I'm trying to do with a simple example.

I have the routes

```
routes.MapRoute("", 
                "Message", 
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", myEnum = MyEnum.Message});

routes.MapRoute("", 
                "", 
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

And the action

```
public ActionResult Index(/*other values*/, MyEnum? myEnum = null)
{
   // do some logic

   var redirectToHomeUrl = userLoggedIn && myEnum.HasValue && myEnum.Value == MyEnum.Message;

   if (redirectToHomeUrl)
   {
      // do some logic
      return RedirectToAction("Index"); <-- problem here
   }

   // Other logic
}
```

Basically the user gets sent to mysite.com/Message and is logged out and shown a model dialogue message over the home page.  When they act on this message and log back in, the page reloads. I detect that they still have the url for the message and want to redirect them back to the home url "mysite.com/".

However return `RedirectToAction("Index")` still retains `myEnum = MyEnum.Message`.

RouteData is persisted after the redirect so I get an infinite loop.

I've tried `RedirectToRoute(null, new { action = "Index", controller = "Home"});`

I've tried `RedirectToAction("Index", new {})`

I've tried `RouteData.Values.Clear()`

I've tried `RouteData.Values["myEnum"] = null;`

If your wondering `RedirectToAction("Index", new { myEnum = null })` doesn't compile :)

Any idea's on how to redirect to the same Action but removing existing route values?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: You don't say that you've tried RouteData.Values.Remove("myEnum").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RedirectToAction("Index", new { myEnum = null })
```

might not compile, but this does:

```
RedirectToAction("Index", new { myEnum = (MyEnum?)null })
```

if *you're* wondering :)

I don't get the point of redirecting to the same action though. If all you want is to remove a value, set it to `null` manually (or ignore it). If you actually want to call a different function (but the same action) (doesn't seem to be the case, but who knows), just return that function's result from yours directly.

Comment: Cheers should have thought of that :). The point of redirecting is to change the displayed url (different parameters values are mapped to different urls). This action is unusual and is done this way mostly to support legacy urls.

Comment: This solution doesn't work.  I'm trying to do something similar, and even when I try to clear my `id` route value using `id = (int?)null`, ASP.NET MVC turns `id` into a query string key instead of part of the route, but it doesn't totally get rid of it.

Comment: You should use `RouteData.Values.Remove("myEnum")`